# How to extend non-log x axis of ln(x) plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to calculate several functions including `ln(x)` on an interval going from 1 to 10. However, I would like to plot on an interval of `x` ranging from `x[-1, 10]`.
So far, I could not modify the ticks as I want, the labels are following the size of my `ln(x)` rather than the value of `x` itself:

```
axiss = np.linspace(-1,10,12)
x = np.linspace(-1, 10, 1002)
s = int(np.where(x == 1)[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.log(x[s:-1]), label='ln(x)')
ax.plot(1/x[s:-1], label='1/x')
ax.plot(-1/(x[s:-1]**2), label='-1/x2')
ax.plot(2/(x[s:-1]**3), label='2/x3')
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlim(-100, 1000)
ax.set_xticklabels(axiss)
```

How could I do to define a range for my x-axis, but only calculate the functions on a part of it ?

I tried:

```
ax.plot(x, np.log(x[s:-1]), label='ln(x)')
```

but of course I have a length issue.

Thank you !

ps: yes I already searched online for ways to do it, asking here is the last resort that I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicity give both x and y lists to matplotlib. This also avoids the need to set the xtick labels manually.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1, 10, 1001)  # don't divide by 0.0
x_for_ln = np.linspace(0.001, 10, 1001)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x_for_ln, np.log(x_for_ln), label='ln(x)')
ax.plot(x, 1/x, label='1/x')
ax.plot(x, -1/(x**2), label='-1/x2')
ax.plot(x, 2/(x**3), label='2/x3')
ax.legend()
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
```

[image: Plot generated by code]